# Specify labels on Imagemagick montage

Tags: imagemagick, montage

Basically I would like something along the lines of

```
> montage -label "picture1|picture2" awesome-photo.jpg crazy-photo.jpg out.jpg
```

result in a out.jpg having the labels picture1 under the first pic, and picture2 under the second. Would I have to do this in two rounds? First label the pics then montage them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
montage -label "picture1" awesome-photo.jpg -label "picture2" crazy-photo.jpg out.jpg
```